# Weird error while uploading to database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm creating app with connection to MySQL Database, I have some working PHP files on my domain already, but now I cannot normally use 1 of PHP files. 
The PHP file looks like that :

```
<?php
    $response = array();

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['dish']) && isset($_POST['review']) && isset($_POST['rating']) && isset($_POST['database_name']) && isset($_POST['UserKeyID']) && isset($_POST['dishphoto']) && isset($_POST['dishsmallphoto'])) {

        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $dish = $_POST['dish'];
        $review = $_POST['review'];
        $rating = $_POST['rating'];
        $database_name = $_POST['database_name'];
        $UserKeyID = $_POST['UserKeyID'];
        $dishphoto = $_POST['dishphoto'];
        $dishsmallphoto = $_POST['dishsmallphoto'];

        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $database_name . "(title, review, rating, dish, dishphoto, dishsmallphoto, UserKeyID) VALUES('$title', '$review', '$rating', '$dish', '$dishphoto', '$dishsmallphoto', '$UserKeyID')");

        if ($result) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

                // echoing JSON response
                echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

                // echoing JSON response
                echo json_encode($response);
        }

    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

In logcat there is something like that :

```
[socket][/] connected
[CDS]rx timeout:0
[CDS]SO_SND_TIMEOUT:0
>doSendRequest
<doSendRequest
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cannot normally use"? What does the PHP error log say?

Comment: It means that PHP file is not working like every other file I was writing and using, I think that it's all about this logcat thing, but I don't know how to make it working

Comment: *"It is not working like every other file"* - what *exactly* happens when you try to run it? Any errors? Anything in the PHP error log? You're not giving us enough info to work with, other than "something's wrong".

Comment: As I said there is this text in logcat which isn't normal, cause I'm using few files in the same app and this text is showing only for this file and as I can see it doesn't pass anything to database.